# BIRT: XML data source cannot be retrieved. XML data source file is invalid or the file doesn't exist

Tags: xml, eclipse, birt

I created an XML data source that fetches XML data from a local application. when creating a data set I get the following error.

```
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: XML data source cannot be retrieved. XML data source file is invalid or the file doesn't exist.
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.ui.wizards.XPathChoosePage.populateXMLTree(XPathChoosePage.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.ui.wizards.XPathChoosePage.createPageCustomControl(XPathChoosePage.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design.ui.wizards.DataSetWizardPage.createControl(DataSetWizardPage.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.setWizard(WizardDialog.java:1182)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1241)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.access$4(WizardDialog.java:1238)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$8.run(WizardDialog.java:1227)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1225)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:915)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:428)
```

The XML URL retuns the following data:

```
<table>
  <row>
    <marketName>dd</marketName>
    <commodityName>Black Barley</commodityName>
    <priceType>Wholesale</priceType>
    <pricePerQtl>58.0</pricePerQtl>
    <date>2014-07-03 15:18:21</date>
  </row>
</table>
```

Comment: can you provide more details like version of software?

Comment: @Miki Spring Tool Suite 

Version: 3.5.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 201405030657
Platform: Eclipse Kepler SR2 (4.3.2)

Comment: I can generate report in BIRT 4.3.2 based on your data. Do you face issue only in application or in BIRT designer too?

Comment: @Miki it works for me when I use XML file as a data source but now when I supply URL to the XML file generator.

Comment: Can you save/check generated XML file? Is URL syntax correct?

Comment: @Miki yes I did :) I don't know why BIRT can't fetch the XML or why it thinks it's incorrect.

Comment: I'm sure you find out if you solve this problem. :)

Comment: @J-Dizzle didn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

I can only reproduce this in only in one scenario i.e there is whitespace before start tag. So make sure that there are no whitespaces.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
  <row>
    <marketName>dd</marketName>
    <commodityName>Black Barley</commodityName>
    <priceType>Wholesale</priceType>
    <pricePerQtl>58.0</pricePerQtl>
    <date>2014-07-03 15:18:21</date>
  </row>
</table>
```

Comment: My XML source doesn't produce the `<?xml` tag and no it doesn't produce a white space at the beginning.

Comment: was the "Test Connection" successful when you were creating data source?

Comment: Yes it was successful.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
This happened to me when I click **this**^ next.

As you can see it is saying `Use the XML file defined in datasource`
but on your datasource you are providing it a `url` so the solution:
 **Use XML file on your data source till you finish your report design.**

Then once you are done with your design point your data source to your `url`.

**OR**
Your `url` needs authentication and the security filter is redirecting you to login page when trying to access the url.
So you may need to:
 *skip authenticating the url* or *somehow authenicate the report engine request.*

Answer (score -1):

I bumped into this issue too with BIRT 4.7.0 on Eclipse 2019-03.

The workaround was to *not* supply an XML Schema (XSD) in the datasource.