# How to authenticate birt report engine requests

Tags: spring, grails, birt, grails-plugin

When designing report I was getting this error:

```
XML data source cannot be retrieved. XML data source file is invalid or the file doesn't exist.
```

[It was asked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575209/birt-xml-data-source-cannot-be-retrieved-xml-data-source-file-is-invalid-or-th/28008466#28008466)

Then I found out it was because the **request was intercepted by my spring security plugin**. Now I disabled the plugin for a moment and my report is working. But this is not solution!

So now I want to somehow configure the report engine to use its own `username` and `password`; To be used when sending the requests.

*Is there any hook in the plugin for doing this or any other workaround?*
**Or**
 when render engine sends a request to the datasource url is possible to add params?
 e.g http://app/report?param1="value"&param2="value". Putting such url on the report design data source field results in invalid url.

**update:**
 I am not using database connection as datasource. 
 my data source is a service that return xml response.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to have some basic user in your DB. 
When you're using the code, use this user to make it, so this user will be used only for these cases.

Comment: sorry for not explaining the datasource I am using. check my updated question

Comment: Am looking for way of providing username and password to the spring security plugin. But dont have clear image abt that.